# Fill a div with a wavy border SVG path

Tags: html, css, svg

I want to fill the `<div>` with the color and add shadow to the border but my code is doing this. I actually need it in the way shown in the image.

```html
<svg height="125" width="1349">
  <path d="M -35 100 s 35 50 75 0" stroke="rgb(255, 195, 56)" stroke-width="5" fill="none" />
  <path d="M 40 100 s 75 -125 150 0" stroke="rgb(255, 195, 56)" stroke-width="5" fill="rgb(255, 195, 56)" />
  <path d="M 190 100 s 35 50 75 0" stroke="rgb(255, 195, 56)" stroke-width="5" fill="none" />
  <path d="M 265 100 s 75 -125 150 0" stroke="rgb(255, 195, 56)" stroke-width="5" fill="rgb(255, 195, 56)" />
  <path d="M 415 100 s 35 50 75 0" stroke="rgb(255, 195, 56)" stroke-width="5" fill="none" />
  <path d="M 490 100 s 75 -125 150 0" stroke="rgb(255, 195, 56)" stroke-width="5" fill="rgb(255, 195, 56)" />
  <path d="M 640 100 s 35 50 75 0" stroke="rgb(255, 195, 56)" stroke-width="5" fill="none" />
  <path d="M 715 100 s 75 -125 150 0" stroke="rgb(255, 195, 56)" stroke-width="5" fill="rgb(255, 195, 56)" />
  <path d="M 865 100 s 35 50 75 0" stroke="rgb(255, 195, 56)" stroke-width="5" fill="none" />
  <path d="M 940 100 s 75 -125 150 0" stroke="rgb(255, 195, 56)" stroke-width="5" fill="rgb(255, 195, 56)" />
  <path d="M 1090 100 s 35 50 75 0" stroke="rgb(255, 195, 56)" stroke-width="5" fill="none" />
  <path d="M 1165 100 s 75 -125 150 0" stroke="rgb(255, 195, 56)" stroke-width="5" fill="rgb(255, 195, 56)" />
  <path d="M 1315 100 s 35 50 75 0" stroke="rgb(255, 195, 56)" stroke-width="5" fill="none" />
  Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg>
```

[image: svg wave border]

Comment: Please add your code and is that your error message that you are getting? Which browser are you using?

Comment: The path coordinates (the values in the `d` attribute) would need to be different. How were they generated for your code?

Comment: i think that these paths are fine for me, the actual what i need is shown in the pick, i am unable to bring this path to front and cant fill the space below this path. Hope u understand. Sorry if the english is bad.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your code, you where creating several path elements where each element had one curveTo subpath. Instead, you need one path element with several curveTo subpaths. In your scenario, the simpler quadratic Bezier curve will work well. After the curveTo subpaths, you will need some lineTo subpaths to define the area under the curves. For example...

```html
<svg height="150" width="880">
  <path d="M 0 100 q 40 -40 80 0 q 40 40 80 0 q 40 -40 80 0 q 40 40 80 0 q 40 -40 80 0 q 40 40 80 0 q 40 -40 80 0 q 40 40 80 0  q 40 -40 80 0 q 40 40 80 0 q 40 -40 80 0 l 0 50 l -880 0 z" stroke="rgb(255, 195, 56)" stroke-width="5" fill="rgb(255, 195, 56)"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 9):

For such a shape, you can use an [svg pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Patterns) and fill a rectangle width the pattern as shown in the following example :

```css
html,body{margin:0;padding:0;}
div{
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/qi5FGET.jpg');
  background-size:cover;
  overflow:hidden;
}
svg{display:block;}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>title</h1>
  <p>whatever content<br/>with several lines</p>
  <svg viewbox="0 0 60 10">
    <pattern x="-7.5" id="waves" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="10" height="10">
      <path d="M0 10 V5 Q2.5 2.5 5 5 T10 5 V10" fill="#FFC338" />
    </pattern>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="60" height="10" fill="url(#waves)"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```