# How do I create a responsive SVG image

Tags: css, html, svg

I want to use SVG to make a wavy line stretch across a page, and it should be responsive, stretching across the page regardless of screen width.

I have seen the sort of thing that I want in this [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37301702/fill-a-div-with-a-wavy-border-svg-path) post but the SVG only produces a fixed width image.

```
<svg height="125" width="1349">
  <path d="M -35 100 s 35 50 75 0" stroke="rgb(255, 195, 56)" stroke-    width="5" fill="none" />
  <path d="M 40 100 s 75 -125 150 0" stroke="rgb(255, 195, 56)" stroke-width="5" fill="rgb(255, 195, 56)" />
  <path d="M 190 100 s 35 50 75 0" stroke="rgb(255, 195, 56)" stroke-width="5" fill="none" />
  <path d="M 265 100 s 75 -125 150 0" stroke="rgb(255, 195, 56)" stroke-width="5" fill="rgb(255, 195, 56)" />
  <path d="M 415 100 s 35 50 75 0" stroke="rgb(255, 195, 56)" stroke-width="5" fill="none" />
  <path d="M 490 100 s 75 -125 150 0" stroke="rgb(255, 195, 56)" stroke-width="5" fill="rgb(255, 195, 56)" />
  <path d="M 640 100 s 35 50 75 0" stroke="rgb(255, 195, 56)" stroke-width="5" fill="none" />
  <path d="M 715 100 s 75 -125 150 0" stroke="rgb(255, 195, 56)" stroke-width="5" fill="rgb(255, 195, 56)" />
  <path d="M 865 100 s 35 50 75 0" stroke="rgb(255, 195, 56)" stroke-width="5" fill="none" />
  <path d="M 940 100 s 75 -125 150 0" stroke="rgb(255, 195, 56)" stroke-width="5" fill="rgb(255, 195, 56)" />
  <path d="M 1090 100 s 35 50 75 0" stroke="rgb(255, 195, 56)" stroke-width="5" fill="none" />
  <path d="M 1165 100 s 75 -125 150 0" stroke="rgb(255, 195, 56)" stroke-width="5" fill="rgb(255, 195, 56)" />
  <path d="M 1315 100 s 35 50 75 0" stroke="rgb(255, 195, 56)" stroke-width="5" fill="none" />
  Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg>
```

A possible solution is to use javascript to repeat the SVG across the width of the page. Or I guess I could chain together a number of the images and use media queries to hide / show enough to fill the page width but that seems a clumsy solution.

Does anyone know of a pure SVG / HTML5 solution?

Comment: Remove `height="125" width="1349"`

Comment: https://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/08/19/making-svgs-responsive-with-css/

Answer (score 3):

You should remove all attributes of specific `width` and `height` from the markup, but you should also add a `viewBox` attribute to the root `svg` tag.

Please check the snippet below.

```css
svg{
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 1349 125">
  <path d="M -35 100 s 35 50 75 0" stroke="rgb(255, 195, 56)" stroke-width="5" fill="none" />
  <path d="M 40 100 s 75 -125 150 0" stroke="rgb(255, 195, 56)" stroke-width="5" fill="rgb(255, 195, 56)" />
  <path d="M 190 100 s 35 50 75 0" stroke="rgb(255, 195, 56)" stroke-width="5" fill="none" />
  <path d="M 265 100 s 75 -125 150 0" stroke="rgb(255, 195, 56)" stroke-width="5" fill="rgb(255, 195, 56)" />
  <path d="M 415 100 s 35 50 75 0" stroke="rgb(255, 195, 56)" stroke-width="5" fill="none" />
  <path d="M 490 100 s 75 -125 150 0" stroke="rgb(255, 195, 56)" stroke-width="5" fill="rgb(255, 195, 56)" />
  <path d="M 640 100 s 35 50 75 0" stroke="rgb(255, 195, 56)" stroke-width="5" fill="none" />
  <path d="M 715 100 s 75 -125 150 0" stroke="rgb(255, 195, 56)" stroke-width="5" fill="rgb(255, 195, 56)" />
  <path d="M 865 100 s 35 50 75 0" stroke="rgb(255, 195, 56)" stroke-width="5" fill="none" />
  <path d="M 940 100 s 75 -125 150 0" stroke="rgb(255, 195, 56)" stroke-width="5" fill="rgb(255, 195, 56)" />
  <path d="M 1090 100 s 35 50 75 0" stroke="rgb(255, 195, 56)" stroke-width="5" fill="none" />
  <path d="M 1165 100 s 75 -125 150 0" stroke="rgb(255, 195, 56)" stroke-width="5" fill="rgb(255, 195, 56)" />
  <path d="M 1315 100 s 35 50 75 0" stroke="rgb(255, 195, 56)" stroke-width="5" fill="none" />
  Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks Juan, I'll give this solution a try as soon as I can get back to this project.

Answer (score 0):

the answer provided @Juan Ferreras should do the trick.
However, if you are trying to put the SVG on a background, you could try something like this :

HTML :

```
<div class="theSVG"></div>
```

CSS :

```
.theSVG {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-image:url('img/my_svg_file.svg');

background-position: center;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;

/* You could even add a Parralax Effect, with a larger image though */    
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
```

}

You'll find an example of that on this website I builded for a school projet : https://victorgutt.com/docs/travaux/promo/index.html

The SVGs are both the logo on the navbar menu and the full page header background. Hope you'll find my answer usefull.

Comment: Welcome to SO! As a warning, please do not post links to your blog/site on every post, as this is frowned apon and considered spam. One link every three or four posts is ok, as long as the links are useful.

Comment: Thanks Victor, I'll give this solution a try as soon as I can get back to this project.